Post-Translational Modification in insulin production
When searching "How is insulin produced commercially" on Google, most results simply say something along the lines of "The insulin gene is inserted into a bacteria, which then express the gene and produce insulin". As far as I know, the peptide produced from the INS gene is subjected to several post-translational modifications to form the actual insulin, but I couldn't find much information on how these PTMs are carried out in the recombinant organisms.
Therefore, my question is: How are post-translational modifications carried out during commercial production of insulin? Do E.Coli and yeast cells just naturally have the machinery to carry out the necessary PTMs on the peptide translated from the INS mRNA, are other genes inserted into the recombinant organisms as well, or is the formed peptide just taken as-is and manually subject to chemical treatment to carry out the needed PTMs?

The wikipedia page on insulin has some information in the last para in the Structural analysis and synthesis section; you might want to follow up the references there.

No E.coli are not able to perform PTMs for insulin production.
But additional genes or special modified strains of E.coli may be used for increased efficiency.
The gene sequence of the proteins is optimized to match the codon use of the strain.
tRNAs can also be coexpressed so that they are not limiting synthesis.
Chaperones can prevent formation of inclusion bodies, which facilitates the workup.
There are two common methods for insulin production:
Expressing proinsulin or expressing A and B chain separately and joining them chemically.
In E.coli the proinsulin sequence (containing a ZZ tail sequence for later purification) is inserted in a plasmid.The expressed protein forms inclusion bodies (protein aggregates of overexpressed protein). Those are isolated, the protein is subjected to multiple chemical treatments and purifications:

Solubilization
Denaturation
Renaturation
Purification over affinity tag chromatography
Site specific cleavage of the C-peptide
Reverse phase chromatography
complexation  with zinc for formulation purposes

For detailed and additional information:
http://bmrat.org/index.php/BMRAT/article/view/692
